# Get min and max of supplier streams

Tags: java, java-8, double, java-stream

I know if i use:

```
double data[][] = new double[n][];
// fill the array

DoubleStream stream = Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream);
int max = stream.max().getAsDouble();

DoubleStream stream = Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream);
int min = stream.min().getAsDouble();
```

i will get the minimum and maximum of whatever value the stream has as a double.

However i cant for the life of me figure out how to make it into a "Supplier". since

```
Supplier<Stream> stream = (Supplier<Stream>) Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream);
double max = stream.max().getAsDouble();
double min = stream.min().getAsDouble();
```

doesn not work, and `Supplier<DoubleStream>` does not work ether.

i managed to get it to work with

```
Supplier<DoubleStream> stream = () -> Arrays.stream(t).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream);
OptionalDouble max = stream.get().max();
OptionalDouble min = stream.get().min();
```

but why did the values in the stream become a OptionalDouble?

Comment: `Supplier<DoubleStream>`

Comment: you have a Supplier, that holds a Stream, so you should make supplier.get().max() or min()...

Answer (score 3):

Casting a `DoubleStream` to a `Supplier<DoubleStream>` does not make a `DoubleStream` a `Supplier<DoubleStream>`.

You need a lambda expression `() -> stream` to form a supplier of the stream:

```
Supplier<DoubleStream> supplier = () -> Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream);
```

The max value then can be determined by:

```
double max = supplier.get().max().orElse(Double.MIN_VALUE); 
// where Double.MIN_VALUE can be any other default 'double' value if max is not present
```

since the `max()` over `DoubleStream` returns an `OptionalDouble`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Supplier<T>` functional interface has a single abstract method:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public Supplier<T> {

    T get();
}
```

As it's a functional interface, you could use a lambda expression (or a method reference) to create an instance of the `Supplier` type:

```
Supplier<Integer> supplier = () -> 1;
```

If you change the `Integer` generic type to `DoubleStream`, then you'd get what you want:

```
Supplier<DoubleStream> supplier = Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToDouble(Arrays::stream);
```

Casting is not magic: if you have a `DoubleStream` instance, you can't just cast that instance to `Supplier<DoubleStream>` and expect the cast to magically transform the stream to a supplier.

Despite all this, it's not clear at all why you need to get a supplier from the stream in the first place.

Regarding the return type of `DoubleStream.max` and `DoubleStream.min` methods, it's `OptionalDouble` (instead of just `double`) because the stream might be empty, in which case there would be neither a max nor a min value. In this case, the returned `OptionalDouble` instance would be empty.